# Cant send image file with whatsapp-web.js

Tags: node.js, whatsapp

I try to send image file with whatsapp-web.js and it does not work; but i don't see any error.
This is my index.js:

```js
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
const { Client,MessageMedia} = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const client=new Client({
    puppeteer: {
        args: ['--no-sandbox']
    }
});

client.on('qr', qr => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true});
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.body);
    const media = MessageMedia.fromFilePath('what.png');
    client.sendMessage(msg.from,media);
});

client.initialize();
```

I can get message and send message. But I can't send image file.

My system

- Ubuntu 22.04.3
- Node js 21.4.0
- WhatsApp web js 1.23.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this. `newFilePath` can be replaced with whatever the path you want to save images it can be root directory. Also you need to access the file you want to send. It is not clear in your code what is `what.png`

```
const fileData = fs.readFileSync(newFilePath, {
                encoding: 'base64',
            })
media = new MessageMedia(
   req.file.mimetype,
   fileData,
   originalFileName,
)
client.sendMessage(msg.from,media)
```